# Using 1-click upgrade module in prestashop with local archive

Tags: prestashop

I am trying to upgrade Prestashop 1.7.8.7 to 8.0.0-beta.1 using autoupgrade module on a test site with real data as an upgrade.

As per the PS beta release notes, I am trying to evaluate a real shop in a test environment using the upgrade module. I have selected "Local Archive" as the channel and put the ZIP into the download folder of admin/autoupgrade but where do i find the XML to upload to this folder?

If i try to use "Local Directory" as the channel, it will not work either as I get an error stating that autoupgrade cannot evaluate if the files are for a valid release.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that updating to 8.0 beta with ZIP file is not working good yet.
You can fill up an [issue](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues) on Github
and consider to try a manual / CLI upgrade as described [here](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/upgrade-module/upgrade-cli/)